# About the space of divisor $L(D):=\{f: \text{meromorphic}, (f)+D\geq 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Q1: I have known that:
If $M$ be a compact Riemann surface. If $D$ is a divisor on $M$ with $d(D)<0$, then $L(D)=\{0\}$.

But how about the situation if remove the condition "compact"?

Q2: what is the dimension $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} L(D)$ is equal under the complex field $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: If it is non-compact, degree is not meaningful in general.

Comment: If it is compact, d(f)=0, why the degree is not meaningful as non-compact?

Comment: Take $M=\mathbb{C}$. Then both 1 and $z$ are meromorphic (in fact holomorphic) functions. But divisor of 1 is zero and divisor of $z$ is one point.

Comment: sorry...I see. But if $M$ is compact, $deg(f)$ is 0...Is it strange?

Comment: Not really. The compactification of the complex plane is the projective line and 1 still has no zeroes or poles, but $z$ has one zero and one pole.